# Python Screenshot Unable to Pick Up Program

Tags: python, windows-7, screenshot, python-imaging-library

I am trying to take a screenshot of a program via Python for OCR.  The screenshot picks up everything except the desired program and its children windows.  I am in Windows 7, and the Windows screenshot function works perfectly.

So far I have tried PIL, Pillow, and Desktopmagic - the latter two are based on PIL, so it is no surprise to me they do not work when PIL does not work.

I am open to any ideas that may work.

Additionally, if possible, I would like to understand *why* this is happening.

Comment: are you trying to capture a video player or a game perhaps?

Comment: Python's screenshot picks up video (Netflix), but not the game.

Comment: the most obvious culprit is hardware acceleration. you'll be luckier if you try to capture from the video hardware instead of the screen

Comment: Thanks, fix.  I'll try that.